# Why are imports shown as undefined within a react component's mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have some pretty standard code overriding mapDispatchToProps. In it I call a static function, authenticate, that is part of an imported class, AuthActions. In both edge and chrome the AuthActions is undefined, but the code runs clean without error. What is going on? Is this just a browser limitation?

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
    actions: {
      authenticate: (userId, password) => {
        debugger;
        let test = AuthActions.authenticate(userId, password);
        dispatch(test);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: What is AuthActions and where is it imported ?

Comment: It is a class that has static members to do authentication. The import call happens at top of my js file.

Comment: @Wylie meant to say: if you do not include that code then no one can help you. Also, the code doesn't run without errors if `AuthActions` is undefined because that's just not possible in any js engine. So either it doesn't run, or its not undefined. Instead of `debugger` try using console.log. The debugging of transpiled code isn't always a smooth operation.

Comment: As mentioned, you need to post more of your code to put this in context. But I'll take a stab at it... My guess is that your import or export syntax is incorrect.  If you have "import AuthActions from './somewhere'", try wrapping AuthActions in curly brackets: "import { AuthActions }...".  If you already have the curly brackets, remove them.  If you have have "{ * as AuthActions} from './auth/actions'", make sure you are exporting the authentication method properly - in that case, without 'default', and not as a child of some other 'actions' object that you're exporting.